# Passing Aysnc Task Results to parent Calling Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to pass the async task result to the calling class. I have created a separate ASync class which is called from other classes. I am passing the response from Async task in "Post Execute" method to calling class method but getting null point exception. Below is my calling method in

```
public boolean getCategories() {

        serUri = "categories.json";
        WebServiceAsyncTask webServiceTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask();
        webServiceTask.execute(serUri,this);

        return true;
    }
```

The method to be executed with result from below aysnc task is

```
public void writeJSONArray(final JSONArray result)
            {


                try {

                for (int i=0; i<result.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString("catname");

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
```

WebServiceAsyncTask Class:

```
public class WebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,JSONArray> {

    ROMSjson roms;
    private static JSONArray json = null;
    private Context context = null;

    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String serviceUrl = (String) params[0];
         final HTTPHelper httph = new HTTPHelper(serviceUrl,context);
         if(serviceUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("categories.json")) {
             json = httph.fetch();

        }else if(serviceUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("categories/create"))
        {

        }

        return json;
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) { // invoked on the ui thread

   roms.writeJSONArray(result);  

   super.onPostExecute(result);

}
```

I am getting null point exception when `roms.writeJSONArray(result)` is called. The result is correctly received before this command. I checked with Log statement. Also if I write the writeJSONArray method in my Async class instead of calling class, all works fine.

I am not sure if I am missing something in passing the result or while calling methods. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Seems you have not created an object from ROMSjson  class
any where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
null pointer exception
```

because `roms is null`

you are declaring  `ROMSjson roms;` inside `WebServiceAsyncTask` but not initializing it !

and using it inside `onPostExecute(JSONArray result)

```
roms.writeJSONArray(result);`  // here roms in null
```

**so** `initialize roms` before using it !

Comment: roms is object for calling class and defined as                            public class WebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,JSONArray> {
 
 ROMSjson roms;                                              Not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: its good you have defined it as public but where are you initializing it ? without initializing all objects are null which are declared though public or private !

Comment: @Gaurav this is the reason for `null pointer exception` because roms is declared but not initialized !

Comment: Thanks a lot Tarsem. Its working now. Was struggling for almost an hours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
        else if(serviceUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("categories/create"))
        {
          // if it falls to this condition then your json object appears to be null
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. However it's not executing this condition. Anyways I removed this block and tried again. Still same issue.

Comment: please read the question again `null point exception when roms.writeJSONArray(result) is called. The result is correctly received before this command` so he is receiving json data without any problem so i think this   `json object appears to be null` is not answer but addition to code !

Answer (score 0):

**Interface is the best way for passing data between classes.**

**create a public interface**

```
public interface WebCallListener{
void onCallComplete(JSONArray result);
}
```

**what to do in your class?**

```
public class WebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,JSONArray> {

    ROMSjson roms;
    private static JSONArray json = null;
    private Context context = null;


    //update
    private WebCallListener local;


    public WebServiceAsyncTask(WebCallListener listener){
     local=listener;
    }
   /////

    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String serviceUrl = (String) params[0];
         final HTTPHelper httph = new HTTPHelper(serviceUrl,context);
         if(serviceUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("categories.json")) {
             json = httph.fetch();

        }else if(serviceUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("categories/create"))
        {

        }

        return json;
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) { // invoked on the ui thread

//update

    super.onPostExecute(result);
   local.onCallComplete(result);  

}
```

**From Your Calling class.**

```
public class CallingClass extends Activity{

 protecte void oncreate(Bundle b){

  new WebServiceAsyncTask(new WebCallListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCallComplete(JSONArray result) {
        //play with your response
    }
   });
 }
}
```